# redirect web page from https to http to avoid dead link

Tags: linux, apache

I have a domain , do not have apply ssl cert .

now the "https://example.com" will go to a dead page.

please advise is it good to do web page redirect ( https to http ) , or just leave it to dead ?

if I want to do redirect ( https to http ) , how to do it , would advise ?

thanks

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/) or [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

you can do with below line command
/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

//VirtualHost *:80//
        . . .

```
    Redirect permanent "/" "https://your_domain_or_IP/"

    . . .
```

//VirtualHost//

easyly :-)
good luck